# Google Sheets - sum a cell from a dynamic list of sheets with vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I update with a new sheet every two days or so and title the name of the sheet the date that it is created. For organizational reasons, I do not want to combine all of the information into one sheet and parse it elsewhere, even though it would make this so much simpler.

I'd like to provide a named range of different sheet names, and have a script, function, etc go to each sheet, grab the contents of a cell and sum them. Bonus points if vlookup can be integrated to ensure that the right cell is being referenced.

So, for example:

```
named range = '7/3/21','7/1/21'
=sum('7/3/21'!B12,'7/1/21'!B12)
```

This is simple enough, but I don't want to alter this every time a new sheet is added to reference the new sheet.

In my mind it would look something like:

```
=sum(vlookup(A1(INDIRECT(NamedRange1&"!c1"))

where:
A1 = the name I want to lookup on the other sheets
NamedRange1 = range of cells that correspond to all of the different sheets
C1 = the cell that I want to add across all the other sheets.
```

Comment: If you need a script, please do research and write the code by yourself instead of asking for solution directly

Comment: Please specify what your question is.

Comment: If your question is about Google Sheets it can't be about Excel. If it's about Excel, please avoid references to Google Sheets. Please modify your question's tags to clarify your interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumacellfromlistofsheets(obj) {
  const listofsheets = obj.list;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~obj.list.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  let sum = 0;
  shts.forEach( sh => {
    sum += sh.getRange(obj.cellinA1Notation).getValue();
  });
}
```